# Trying to find the generic coefficient of a hypergeometric series

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I begin with

```
FullSimplify[Series[HypergeometricPFQ[{-k,m/2-1,(m-1)/2,m/2},{1/2,1,3m/2-k-2},t],{t,0,3}],
  Assumptions->k\[Element]Integers\[And]m\[Element]Integers\[And]k>=0\[And]m>0]
```

and obtain

[image]

Now I want to get a formula for the $j$th coefficient. Of course it is easy to guess it but then I should prove it, and also there are more complicated cases. So I try

```
FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[HypergeometricPFQ[{-k,m/2-1,(m-1)/2,m/2},{1/2,1,3m/2-k-2},t],{t,0,j}],
  Assumptions->k\[Element]Integers\[And]m\[Element]Integers\[And]k>=0\[And]m>0]
```

The result (on 11.0.1.0) is zero. I would understand if the engine would reply that it cannot compute it, but why zero??

Comment: It seems like the `k>=0` assumption makes it zero. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks for this observation! I confirm that without the `k>=0` I seem to obtain correct result. Which is even more strange since there are definitely nonzero cases with nonnegative `k`. You can observe this by computing the above series using, say, `With[{k=3},`...`]`

Comment: `FullSimplify[
 Piecewise[{{1/(-1 - k)!, j >= 0}}, 0],
 Assumptions -> 
  k \[Element] Integers \[And] m \[Element] Integers \[And] 
   k >= 0 \[And] m > 0]` returns zero. So does `Table[1/(-1 - k)!, {k, 100}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well this is understandable. But in these coefficients, all negative factorials occasionally cancel out, how to deal with these cases?

Comment: Take the limits as `k` approaches an integer? However, `Limit[(Gamma[j - k]  Gamma[-2 - k + (3 m)/2])/(Gamma[-k]  Gamma[-2 + j - k + (3 m)/2]), k -> k0,  Assumptions ->  k0 \[Element] Integers \[And] m \[Element] Integers \[And] m > 0 && j >= 0 && k0 >= 3]` returns `0` even though the limits at specific values of `j` and `m` are generally nonzero. I'd be inclined to call the zero limit a bug, since it's not even generically true.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to use the following code for the nth term of
the series

```
HypergeometricPFQn[a_List, b_List, z_, n_] := z^n/n!
  Product[Pochhammer[ai, n], {ai, a}]/Product[Pochhammer[bi, n], {bi, b}];
```